# Does this matrix multiplication property always apply?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm working on a derivation in a statistics textbook and came across the following formula, which I needed to simplify, and I'm wondering if there is a straight forward rule I could've applied.

I got to this point in my simplification:
$$
E[(\textbf{y} - E\textbf{y})^TX[(X^TX)^{-1}]^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(\textbf{y}-E\textbf{y})]
$$

I can see that this is essentially analogous to the univariate formula

$$
E[\frac{(y-Ey)^2x^2}{x^4}]
$$

but since the " $x^2$ " matrix-equivalent term in the "numerator" is split on either side of the "denominator" (inverse matrices), I wasn't sure whether it's possible to simply state that they will multiply together with the "denominator" and cancel out (become an identity matrix).

After more work I was able to simplify the equation and get what I wanted, but I'm not sure whether I did extra work and this is a generally applicable rule.

Comment: At the very least, we could simplify further by noting that $[(X^TX)^{-1}]^T = (X^TX)^{-1}$.

Comment: Is this an expectation over $\mathbf y$? Is $X$ a constant matrix?

Comment: Assuming you are working with the linear case (i.e. $E(y) = X\beta$ and $(X'X)^{-1}X'y = \hat{\beta}$), then your expression eventually reduce to $E((\hat{\beta} - \beta)'(\hat{\beta} - \beta))$. Is this your desired result?

Comment: In general, you can't just say "things cancel" since these aren't scalars. The only rule you are allowed to use is cyclic permutation under the trace operator, and in this case I don't see how it applies